# wp_get_archives breakes Html5 validation

Tags: wp-get-archives

I have a issue with **wp_get_archives** because it breaks my **Html5** validation.

Inside validator I get this message: **Bad value archives for attribute rel on element link: Not an absolute IRI. The string archives is not a registered keyword or absolute URL.**
My archive links looks like this:   
http://robertpeic.com/wordpress_template/2013/01/' />

http://robertpeic.com/wordpress_template/2012/12/' />

I am guessing that those errors are happening because spaces inside my links, now if I change my **Doctype** into **Strict** my page validates **fine**. 
Can someone please tell me how can I validate my page as **HTML5**? Thank you!!

My wp_get_archives looks like this:`wp_get_archives('type=monthly&format=link');`
[Validator link](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Frobertpeic.com%2Fwordpress_template%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just remove the `wp_get_archives()` call from the document head altogether. Why even have it there?

Otherwise, this isn't really **WordPress**-specific. [`rel="archives"` is valid for `<link>` tags in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/links.html#rel-archives).

Comment: If I remove it than my Archive Widget won't work.

Comment: What Archive Widget?

Comment: Ups sorry it work's fine and validates... I meant sidebar archive widget. Thank you for your time and help. Much appreciated!!!